# Android Studio alert: Could not find null:unspecified:null

Tags: android, android-studio, jcenter

I developed a library module, then uploaded the aar to JCenter, and approved .  When I resolved the lib in build.gradle of my project,it show me those messages:

Could not find null:unspecified:null.
Searched in the following locations:

```
file:/Users/hyd/tools/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/extras/m2repository/null/unspecified/null/unspecified-null.pom
file:/Users/hyd/tools/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/extras/m2repository/null/unspecified/null/unspecified-null.jar
file:/Users/hyd/tools/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/null/unspecified/null/unspecified-null.pom
file:/Users/hyd/tools/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/null/unspecified/null/unspecified-null.jar
file:/Users/hyd/tools/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/null/unspecified/null/unspecified-null.pom
file:/Users/hyd/tools/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/null/unspecified/null/unspecified-null.jar
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/null/unspecified/null/unspecified-null.pom
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/null/unspecified/null/unspecified-null.jar
https://jcenter.bintray.com/null/unspecified/null/unspecified-null.pom
https://jcenter.bintray.com/null/unspecified/null/unspecified-null.jar
```

Required by:
    project :app > com.yundong.zmui:zmui:0.0.2

used commandj：
gradle version: https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip

build command: gradlew build

upload to JCenter command：gradlew clean build bintrayUpload -PbintrayUser= -PbintrayKey=key -PdryRun=false

How to solve it !

Comment: How did you build and upload your library? What plugin did you use? Please add the build.gradle to your question.

Comment: I used the command："gradlew build" to build, and my gradle version is "https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip"

Comment: You need to add your build.gradle code to your question so other can help you.

Comment: I upload use the command : gradlew clean build bintrayUpload -PbintrayUser= -PbintrayKey=key -PdryRun=false

Comment: OK, I'll do it . It is the first time I ask question in stackoverflow. thanks for your advice